# Passing form variable dynamically to Django template tag

Tags: jquery, django

I want to pass a variable to django template tag dynamically but I could not succeed.

```
<input id="country" />
<div id="button"> Button </div>

$('#button').click(function(){
    var dynamicVar=$('#country').val(); 
    var tags= {    
    source: {% url myView dynamicVar %}  /* but {% url myView 'someValue' %} works */
    select: function(event, s){
        $("#city").val(s.label);
        };
    $("#city").autocomplete(tags);
});
```

I am getting this NoReverseMatch error, saying the dynamicVar is not passed.

The long story: I am trying to get 2 cascaded dropdown lists. User selects a country, then City input becomes available. I want city field to be auto-completed field. Currently, without country field, it works but the query is slow. So I want to pre-filter it.

Comment: where is your template tag codes?

Comment: I use url template tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057318/passing-variable-urlname-to-url-tag-in-django-template

Comment: Look carefully at your rendered page, `var dynamicVar` is at client side.

Comment: @iMom0 yes I am trying to understand how can I pass the client side variable to server without loading another view.

Comment: @UszyWieloryba I had tried that, no success either, its just for passing context variables.

Comment: If you are passing `str value`, it must be `'dynamicVar'` or `country=dynamicVar`. I don't know your url codes so I'm defining country as passing parameter for just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% url myView dynamicVar %}` is rendered on the server side, so you have to:

```
var dynamicVar = $('#country').val(); 
var url = 'http://your_site.com/autocomplete_country/' + dynamicVar + '/'
```

To avoid hardcoding server name in the template, use [`request.get_host`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host)

Comment: I guess this probably should work, I need to check when I get back to my workstation and select as the answer if it works.